# Removing all duplicate images with different filenames from a directory

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a folder and delete any file that is a duplicate image (but different name). After running this script all files get deleted except for one. There are at least a dozen unique ones out of about 5,000. Any help understanding why this is happening would be appreciated.

```
import os
import cv2 

directory = r'C:\Users\Grid\scratch'
 
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    a=directory+'\\'+filename
    n=(cv2.imread(a))
    q=0
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        b=directory+'\\'+filename
        m=(cv2.imread(b))
        comparison = n == m
        equal_arrays = comparison.all()
        if equal_arrays==True and q==1:
            os.remove(b)
        q=1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code, but I am going to suggest an alternate strategy.

A more efficient way would be to collect `md5` or `sha1` hashes of the files, into a set or some other container, while iterating the directory.  Then when you calculate the hashes you can check if that particular hash already exists in the collection which would indicate the file is a duplicate of one that you have already seen and therefore should be removed.

Additional pointers: You only need to get the directory contents once. So there should be no reason to call `os.listdir()` more than once on the same directory.

for example:

```
import hashlib
import os

hashes = set()

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    digest = hashlib.sha1(open(path,'rb').read()).digest()
    if digest not in hashes:
        hashes.add(digest)
    else:
        os.remove(path)
```

You can use a more secure hash if you would like but the chances of encountering a collision are astronomically low.